# I can't get anything to return from this RSS parser

Tags: node.js, cron, rss

I have a SQL DB with RSS urls. I want to use cron to trigger a request of the feeds every couple of hours (cron is set to every minute to get a return at the moment). When I get a return I want to put those into the DB for an aggregating site.

This is as far as I can get. I know something looks off, can't put my finger on it.

```
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function () {
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    pool.connect()
        .then(function (client) {
            client.query(
                    'SELECT * FROM rss_url;')
                .then(function (result) {
                    client.release();
                    result.forEach(function (rss) {
                        parser.parseURL(rss, function (err, parsed) {
                            console.log('parsed.feed ', parsed.feed);
                            parsed.feed.entries.forEach(function (entry) {
                                console.log('entry ', entry);
                                client.query(
                                    'INSERT INTO article (contentSnippet, guid, link, title, category) ' +
                                    'VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [entry.contentSnippet, entry.guid, entry.link, entry.title, entry.category])
```

Comment: So... which part of this works, and at what point does it break down? For example, have you confirmed if the `GET` request is properly triggered (and henceforth received by the server) every minute?

Comment: The parser returns objects when I tried it out in npm's runkit. I don't know much about how to test this. I had console logs in there but I'm not seeing any of them. I'm only a few months into coding, so I don't know much about debugging or how to walk through it to see where it breaks down. I tried using node inspector and it would crash chrome when I tried. Thanks.

Comment: I've been using Atom. I just downloaded VSC and I'll research debugging with that for now.

Comment: Great! I'd recommend removing all the code out of a `cron.schedule()` method (in case it complicates what's happening) and focus on making just the code itself work (perhaps via a `setInterval`)... or even better, remove everything from `cron.schedule()` and start adding things one line at a time, while verifying (as much as possible) that the changes you think you're making are indeed happening. For example, one thing to verify is "does my server receive a `GET` request every minute as a direct result of this scheduled task?"

Comment: Got it up and running. Thanks